# Best design for dependent tables in a Work Order Database

Tags: sql, database-design

Im working in a database to control work orders but I have some troubles with the design of a database.

I have one table:

```
TABLE WorkOrder
 - WorkOrderID 
 - DateOfRequest 
 - Requestor 
 - DrawingNumber 
 - Quantity
```

But I don't have any idea how to create the following tables in a normalized way:

An order must have only one status: Approved or Rejected.

- **Approved** orders have an `ApprovedBy` field, and fall in one of these two scenarios:

  - **Delivered**: if an order is Delivered it should contain `DeliveredDate`, `ReceivedBy` and `ReceivedQuantity`. We need the quantity because a received quantity could be less or more than the requested quantity.
  - **Canceled**: if an order is Canceled it should contain `CancelDate`, `CanceledBy` and `CanceledReason`.
- **Rejected** orders have `RejectedBy` and `RejectedReason` fields only.

I hope that some one could give me an idea to deal with this brainstorm

Comment: Assuming you don't need to track multiple states of Approved, Rejected, then you should just put _all_ of those fields in the same table. Optionally you could add check constraints that ensure that records that are Approved must have RejectedBy and RejectedReason = NULL etc. The important question is: Do you need to track multiple changes in state over time? The only reason you'd put these in another table is if a given work order had many changes over time to track.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a structure that looks something like this:

```
    TABLE work_orders
     - id
     - drawing
     - quantity

    TABLE statuses
     - id
     - work_order_id (foreign key to work_orders)
     - by            (covers requested by, approved by, rejected by and canceled by)
     - date
     - type        (delivered | canceled | rejected | requested)

    TABLE receptions  
     - id            (same as the status id, one-to-one)
     - quantity  

    TABLE cancelations
     - id            (same as the status id, one-to-one)  
     - reason

    TABLE rejections
     - id            (same as the status id, one-to-one)  
     - reason
```

When you create an order, you add an entry in your work_orders table, as well as a new status of type requested.

When the order is delivered, you add a new status, and a reception with the same id. You could even handle multiple partial deliveries with this system.

When the order gets rejected or canceled, you add the status and also an entry in the corresponding table. These tables could be merged, but if you ever decide to store different info for these types of status, you'll be in trouble, so I would probably separate them from the start.

To know the current status of an order, you just query the status table, order by date, and get the last entry. You can even show the entire timeline of an order, by fetching all corresponding statuses. Also, this structure allows you to have part of an order delivered, and the rest canceled.

I hope it all makes sense. Feel free to ask if you want me to elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

You have two status values, Approved and Rejected. Approved is further subdivided into two sub-status values, Delivered and Canceled. Let's start out by saying we have three status values, Rejected, Delivered and Canceled and see how our design works out.

The WorkOrder table will be as shown in the question, so we need a Status table that will associate the status with the work order, contain any data common to all status values and give us a hint as to where the data for the status may be found.

```
create table Status(
    WOID    int  primary key,
    Value   char( 1 ) check( Value in ('R', 'D', 'C' )),
    By      int   not null, -- who approved, rejected or authorized this status
    AsOf    date  not null, -- and when.
    constraint FK_Status_WorkOrder( WOID)
        references WordOrder( ID ),
    constraint FK_By_Employee( By )
        references Employee( ID )
);
```

At this point, we know there will be multiple tables used to contain status details (named, as a guess, something like Rejects, Deliveries, Cancels). But we can't define one field that will be a FK to each of these other tables and defining three such fields will complicate both design and the data integrity maintenance of the running database. Fortunately, there is a way around it.

What we do is have the FKs in the three detail tables referring back to the Status table. But first, we have to prepare the Status table by adding one additional constraint:

```
create table Status(
    ...,
    constraint UQ_Status_By_Type unique( WOID, Value )
);
```

If you're paying attention, you may be wondering why we would create a unique index on two fields, one of which is unique all by itself. The reason is to define a hook the three detail tables can latch onto.

```
create table Rejects(
    WOID    int  primary key,
    Value   char( 1 ) check( Value = 'R' ),
    Reason  varchar( 10 ),
    constraint FK_Rejects_Status( WOID, Value )
        references Status( WOID, Value )
);
```

The other detail tables are defined similarly.

Let's examine what we have so far. The WOID field of the Status table assures there can be no more than one status for any work order and the check constraint assures it must be one of either Rejected, Delivered or Canceled. If a WO status is defined as, say, Rejected, an entry must be made in the Status table with a Value of 'R'. Thus only a corresponding entry in the Rejects table (which can contain only a value of 'R') can be made for that WO. An entry in the Delivered table (which can have only a status value of 'D') would be rejected by the system.

Thus data integrity is maintained. Unfortunately, data integrity is too often shoe-horned in at the end of the design. I think it should be the primary design principle.

Refinements are possible, of course. For example, rather than using a check constraint the Value field of the Status table could itself be a foreign key to a lookup table. That would make it easy to add new status values at some later time.